# 406 JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows when RLS is enabled on Supabase

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, supabase, postgrest, supabase-database

I have looked at various solutions on StackOverflow, github issues in supabase, supabase/postgrest-js, postgRESTPostgREST/postgrest, and searched the Discord as well. But none of the solutions have been working so far.

The code works as expected, but as soon as I turn on RLS on Supabase. The request will return the below 406 error.

```js
export const supabase = createClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY)

const { data, error } = await supabase.from('profiles').select('*').eq('id', userId).maybeSingle()
// const { data, error } = await supabase.from('profiles').select('*').eq('id', userId).limit(1).single() // works when RLS disabled
// const { data, error } = await supabase.from('profiles').select('*').eq('id', userId).single() // works when RLS disabled
```

Response before RLS

```js
{
    "id": "123-123-1241-1231",
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T03:59:22.751125+00:00",
    "is_subscribed": false,
    "interval": null,
    "email": "test@example.com"
}
```

Response after turning on RLS

```js
{
    "message": "JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned",
    "details": "Results contain 0 rows, application/vnd.pgrst.object+json requires 1 row"
}
```

I've tried schema reload, re-implement the policy, but none's been working so far.

I have a "profile" table its "id" column referencing the "auth.users.id".

The policy's target role is currently "anon" but I've tried "authenticated" as well.

```
(uid() = id)
```

I also tried to change the table name to "profiles" (plural) instead of "profile" but no luck.

Comment: What is `uid()`? What do you want the RLS policy to do?

Comment: @Bergi `uid()` is a helper function that returns the ID of the user. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#authuid

Answer (score 0):

Got help from Supabase's Discord and resolved the problem.

Thanks `@garyaustin` from Discord!

> My guess is you don't have a logged in user (or jwt) in that case when the call is made. If you set to policy to true and anon works that confirms no logged in user at point of call.

I'm using NextJS and cookie were attached on client-side requests but didn't attach jwt on server-side requests.

Included token and RLS was working with `authenticated` role.

`supabase.auth.setAuth(access_token)`